# Convert numbers in a MySql database

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm need to convert some numbers in a database.

I have the column 'Price' where The price is written like for USD 10 it is written like 1000 instead of 10.00

Do anyone know how I can convert all the numbers in this column to number/100?

I would also like to add 25% to all the numbers if this is possible?

The database is running on a Ubuntu Server where I have full root access, so it is possible to make a custom script there.

Comment: Are you changing the column data types? Are you coverting the same column or are you saving the new number to another column?

Comment: You want to divide by 100 and multiply with 1.25. You should also think about the number of desired digits: 1234 * 1.25 / 100 = 15.425, which is fifteen Dollars and fourty-two and a half Cents. Do you want fractions of Cents?

Comment: What is the data type of the price column? If it's integer, you will have to change the type to something else so it will store the decimal number. If it's varchar, you can format the number after converting. Edit your question and show the schema of the table (at least the definition of the price column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add 25% and divide by 100:

```
UPDATE test
SET price = price *1.25/100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the division:

```
select price / 100
```

If you want to fix the data, use `update`:

```
update t
    set price = price / 100;
```

You can adjust the arithmetic for whatever factor you want to multiply by.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to your problem:

```
UPDATE Table_Name
SET PRICE = (PRICE / 100) * 1.25
```